# What could be the reason behind a PC not turning on after changing the hard drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply, usb-boot

Just recently I was trying to install Windows 10 on my new SSD drive, while having HDD unconnected. Then I booted autoinstaller from USB and found out that my SSD was missing from the list(possibly because it wasn't initialized first). After that, I shut down the PC and reconnected the HDD drive(to initizalize the SSD from it) without changing anything else. Now, the PC **won't turn on at all**; it doesn't start the fans and the motherboard. I guess that either the motherboard is dead, or the power supply, but it seems a bit strange because the only thing I've changed since it was working was the hard drive. I've already checked the minor connections and problems, like a disconnected power button and the motherboard's battery.

Could be there some other possible reasons for this unhappy event?

Comment: Have you tried jump-starting your power supply with a paperclip to rule that out? Have you tried shorting the power button pins with a small metal object (tip of a screwdriver) to see if you have a faulty power button cable?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yep, I have just done that. I guess that leaves me with the dead motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some time, I tried to turn it on again without changing it, and it worked! I think that's very likely due to overheating; my PC heats a lot.

Comment: Could also be a cable that was *barely* making contact, and was moved during assembly. As for heat, that's abnormal. Are fans working and case clean?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes, all the fans are working properly, on motherboard, power supply, video card and the outer fan. As for the case, it is not perfectly clean, but I regularly clean out the most of the dust.